# discriminant of a polynomial of degree 2 in 3 variables

Tags: discriminant

Which is the correct way/ method/Formula to find the discriminant of a quadratic equation in 3 variables?

Also, how to conclude that, whether this f is reducible or irreducible?

Some one knows this please help

Comment: Check this link hope this works : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurveDiscriminant.html